# Mapbox in react (ReferenceError: L is not defined)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mapbox

I'm trying to get react mapbox to work in a small project.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mapboxmap

```
import React from 'react';
import MapboxMap from 'react-mapbox';

class Operator extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='container'>
            <MapboxMap
                    mapId="mapbox.comic"
                zoomControl={false}
                center={[59.907433, 30.299848]} zoom={17}
                />


  </div>
 );
}
}

export default Operator;
```

Just like they say on the description page for the npm package. However, all I get is this error message:

```
ReferenceError: L is not defined
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that your exact code? What are those extra `<div>`s ??

Comment: Ah yes I copied the example here and I get the same error (after removing the spelling mistake they had) http://www.webpackbin.com/EJGOiZDG-

Comment: This is a comment from the component `// Assuming Mapbox/Leaflet is already exposed as `L`` so I tried `npm install mapbox.js` but I need an api key

Comment: Which eventually leads me here https://www.mapbox.com/help/create-api-access-token/

Comment: I have a token, but don't see where I should enter it?

Comment: I got this error because of SSL sertificates

Answer (score 1):

Try adding 
`<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>`

From the [github page](https://github.com/iamale/MapboxMap)

`Notice: this never was a full-feature library, merely a layer on top of Mapbox JS SDK. For a better, more full fledged solution, try react-leaflet (in conjunction with the Mapbox Maps API in our case).`

Answer (score 1):

This is what you wanted to do ->

import L from 'leaflet';